# Find the last level before NULL starts appearing in columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have max 10 levels of an article. I want to find the maximum level of an article from a table whose structure looks like below image.
[image]

The expected output is :
[image]

eg for Article A maximum level is in F5.
also if there is same value from F2 to F10 we should ignore that record.

Please help.

Regards,
R

Comment: Your table does not have optimal design, and the F columns should ideally appear across separate _rows_, not across columns.

Comment: A database table is not a spreadsheet. You may want to start over, or abandon the idea of using an RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a giant `case` expression:

```
select f1,
       (case when max(f10) is not null then 10
             when max(f9) is not null then 9
             when max(f8) is not null then 8
             when max(f7) is not null then 7
             when max(f6) is not null then 6
             when max(f5) is not null then 5
             when max(f4) is not null then 4
             when max(f3) is not null then 3
             when max(f2) is not null then 2
       end) as max_level
from t
where not (f2 <=> f3 and f3 <=> f4 and . . . )
group by f1;
```